# use a variable for percentage bar width html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a percentage bar and I need to make it dynamic. So I have a script that calculate the percentage and I need to use the result to update the bar.

```
<html>
<script>

function myF(){
    const and=["1","2","3"];
    const myand=["1","2"];
    var la=and.length;
    var lm=myand.length;
    var mywid=0;

    for (let i=0; i<la; i++){
        for(let j=0; j<lm; j++){
            if(and[i]==myand[j])
                mywid++;
            }
        }
    }
    const perc=(99/la)*mywid;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = perc0;
</script>


<body onload="myF()">
<div class="w3-border">
  <div class="w3-grey" style="MY VARIABLE PERC"></div>
</div>
```

But how? I tried with `<p id="output></p>` but it doesn't work

Comment: The same way you updated the innerHTML, `document.getElementById('output').style.width = \`${perc}%\``

Comment: Please make your code (now a snippet) actually work. This helps people answer your question with a working answer.

Comment: see [How TO - JavaScript Progress Bar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There is an accessor for the style attribute on every stylable element.
You've already retrieved the output element and updated the inner HTML. Updating other attributes is also the same.

```
const perc = (99 / la) * mywid;
const element = document.getElementById('output');

element.innerHTML = perc;
element.style.width = `${perc}%`;
```

```js
const preview = document.getElementById('preview');
const btn0 = document.getElementById('0-btn');
const btn20 = document.getElementById('20-btn');
const btn40 = document.getElementById('40-btn');
const btn60 = document.getElementById('60-btn');
const btn80 = document.getElementById('80-btn');
const btn100 = document.getElementById('100-btn');

btn0.addEventListener('click', () => updatePreview(0));
btn20.addEventListener('click', () => updatePreview(20));
btn40.addEventListener('click', () => updatePreview(40));
btn60.addEventListener('click', () => updatePreview(60));
btn80.addEventListener('click', () => updatePreview(80));
btn100.addEventListener('click', () => updatePreview(100));

function updatePreview(val) {
  preview.style.width = `${val}%`;
}
```

```css
.root {
  padding: 10px;
}

.preview {
  height: 50px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="controls">
    <button id="0-btn">0%</button>
    <button id="20-btn">20%</button>
    <button id="40-btn">40%</button>
    <button id="60-btn">60%</button>
    <button id="80-btn">80%</button>
    <button id="100-btn">100%</button>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="preview" class="preview"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the patience and the exhaustive answer. But I still find hard to understand how I can use my variable 'perc' to update the percentage bar, since it has to be updated automatically without a button.

Comment: The trick is calling the function that updates the width every time your percentage changes. Be it when the page loads or when the percentage is calculated.